# ARIA make reader read non-focused element content

Tags: javascript, html, css, wai-aria

I have elements on a page which are "focusable" (buttons, elements with tabindex etc) and screen reader reads the content just fine.

However, I have some other elements that are not focusable (due to the fact there are lots of them - dropdown list results etc), so I don't want user to click tab countless times, but they are navigable through left/right/up/down keys, and they get CSS class "selected" (although some other element - their parent - is actually focused)

**I want to make reader read those specific elements, with the class "selected". How do I do it?**

(I tried applying attribute aria-label="read this" to them, but it didn't work; it works only if element is actually focused)

---

Here's more details to help you understand what I want to achieve:

```
<div tabindex="0" >
  <span>title1</span>
  <ul>
    <li class="selected">item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div tabindex="0">
  <span>title2</span>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d5gbjst1/1/

You can tab back and forth between those 2 divs and any screen reader (I tried with Windows Narrator, NVDA and JAWS) will read "title1" and all the items for the first one and "title2" and all the items for the second, **depending where the focus is**.

Notice class "selected" on the first item in the first ul. Now, I browse with the up/down arrows through my ul lists, and class "selected" shifts from item to item accordingly. (That's the separate JS code, not included in this example for simplicity sake)

When the class "selected" is applied to the element, I want to force reader to read it. Is it possible at all?

---

Edit: I tried also adding attributes to ul and li, still no luck:

```
<ul role="list">
 <li role="listitem">
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem the other week, the solution I went with was to use 
`aria-describedby` and also `aria-label` to provide the extra info from around the page in the element that currently has focus.

In one case we change the content of `aria-label` to provide extra details only on the first time the element has focus.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My element with the class "selected" and it never receives focus. His state is never focused (as in browser focused, rule (":focus") is never true for it)

Comment: You missunderstand me, on the item that has the focus, add an aria label that gives info about the element you want read out. You can not directly do what you want to do, but you can fake it

Comment: It is impossible for me to add to "ul" element labels of each "li" element

Comment: You can use aria-discribedby to list the IDs of each LI to have them all read out. It’s not pretty, but unfortunately it is often the only way.

Comment: Why would I do it? Why wouldn't I just use aria-label instead of aria-labelledby some other element? You miss the point, I don't want "li" elements to be focused.

Comment: Lack of other options

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently and during research, I found information about aria-activedescendant attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-activedescendant_attribute

In this case, every list element should have a unique id attr. When the list element is selected, its id should be provided to the aria-activedescendant attr of the focused parent.

```
<div tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="Id1">
  <span>title1</span>
  <ul>
    <li class="selected" id="Id1">item1</li>
    <li id="Id2">item2</li>
    <li id="Id3">item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This kind of worked but the navigation of dropdown using arrow keys no longer works

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make reader read those specific elements, with the class
>   "selected". How do I do it?

I don't think you should try to do that. Screen readers - especially the ones you have tested with - have intricate keybinds to allow users to navigate to, from, and between specific elements and then jump in and out of them.

Forcing a non standard behaviour for accessible technologies could create a frustrating experience for those users.

> Edit: I tried also adding attributes to ul and li, still no luck:
>
> `<ul role="list">  <li role="listitem">`

Avoid setting roles for lists, as they have these assigned by default. See here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/grouping-content.html#ref-for-allowed-aria-role-attribute-values%E2%91%A1%E2%91%A0

> Notice class "selected" on the first item in the first ul. Now, I
>   browse with the up/down arrows through my ul lists, and class
>   "selected" shifts from item to item accordingly. (That's the separate
>   JS code, not included in this example for simplicity sake)
>
> When the class "selected" is applied to the element, I want to force
>   reader to read it. Is it possible at all?

I have tested using narrator and Screen Reader Simulator for Chrome with your jsfiddle. The expected behaviour, and what I have managed to reproduce, is what you are aiming for. Correct me if I am wrong?

First, I click tab and focus on the following piece of markup:

```
<div tabindex="0" >
  <span>title1</span>
  <ul>
    <li class="selected">item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Which results in the screen reader returning

> "title1, item1, item2, item3"

in quick succession. As I would expect.

I click tab again to focus on this piece of markup:

```
<div tabindex="0">
  <span>title2</span>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the screen reader returns

> "title 2, item1, item2, item3"

in quick succession. Again, as I would expect

Finally, I click tab again to set focus back to the first piece of markup and use the downarrow key. The screen reader returns

> "Enter list. One of three. Bullet. Item 1"

I then click the downarrow key again to move to the second bullet.

> "Two of three. Bullet. Item 2."

I click the downarrow key again.

> "Three of three. Bullet. Item 3".

This behaviour is what I would expect and is - from what experience I have of passing two Double-A WCAG 2.1 assessments - the norm.

What behaviour are you expecting. Specifically, what is it you want your screen reader to return/say?

Comment: I don't get the results as you do. When I use Windows Narrator I get only "down arrow" and "up arrow" when clicking down and up arrows. As for NVDA the up and down behaviour is blocked for some reason (some hotkeys probably highjacked it), and as for JAWS up and down arrows have the same effect as tabbing back and forth.

Comment: It sounds as if your narrator - and perhaps other assistive technologies - are announcing your key presses instead of actually following your on-screen navigation. I have confirmed again with Narrator this morning and replicated my above answer's behaviour.

Comment: I had the same result (down arrow/up arrow) when I installed Screen Reader Simulator for Chrome. I use Win10 and latest Chrome. I don't know how it's possible for me to have a different result than you.

Comment: Something for you to check: In your Narrator settings, scroll down to "Change what you hear when typing" and ensure that checkbox 1, 2, and 5 are ticked. That is the default settings.

Comment: I have default settings of Narrator, and the Narrator works fine conserning tab

Comment: Sorry I don't have an option you mentioned.

Comment: Go to the start menu, type "ease of access narrator settings", scroll down to "Change what you hear when typing".

Comment: I just realized, colleague next to me has different list of options for Narrator than me ??? He has the option you've mentioned. What do I do to upgrade it?

Comment: That would be an entirely separate troubleshooting from the original question. Test on your colleagues machine to see if you can replicate the behaviour first. That will answer your original question.

It is entirely possible that your 3rd party assistive software may disable parts of Narrator.

Comment: I'm fixing the Windows and Narrator and will get back when I test it in updated Narrator. However, I guess you would be right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205512/discussion-between-dvro-and-dalibor).

Comment: No need to. You made your point. I still don't know how to make some particular element readable that is not focusable. Review my post title, and my last sentence: "When the class "selected" is applied to the element, I want to force reader to read it. Is it possible at all?"

Comment: "how to make some particular element readable that is not focusable" - What element might that be? If the markup of the page is correct then the screen reader should read everything - regardless of if it is focusable. The only thing I could consider to forcing the screen reader to read anything with "selected" applied to it would be using javascript to assign it as an alert, but that would be the worst solution as that goes against accessibility standards.

Comment: Well it's important that the reader reads alerts (actually, I had short toaster popup in mind that announces error when login unsuccessful), but I don't want to switch focus to it.

Comment: The only thing you could try is to add role=alert to the element, and append either "Error:" or "Alert:" to the browser title. However, that very likely won't be enough to achieve what you are saying. The standard for alerts with screen readers is the following: 1) Add "Error:" to the browser title so the reader announces it as soon as possible, 2) Display the error or a summary of errors, 3) Move focus to the error or summary. You said you want that to occur when a login is unsuccessful, meaning the reader will be focused on your login button. You would have to redirect focus I'm afraid.

Comment: Any further forward with your testing?

Comment: The browsing with up/down keys is now the same as you posted, as I expected that would be the same when I upgrade Windows. However, I still can't get non-focusable elements such as toaster to be read.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle of your toaster?

Comment: It would take me too much time to set it all up, it's a plugin for angular.

Comment: The toaster is wrapped in a div - I'm assuming? If so, a piece of JS can target that div when it appears and the screen reader will read it. But that is redirecting focus.

Comment: There is no success in the attempt to make non-focusable elements readable by reader, so I will stop here. You earned the bounty because of your effort, but I will not mark this answer as an answer because we didn't solve the original problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding tab index to those specific elements, but you should be careful when using it as it can lead to pages that can be really hard to navigate if you use values greater than 0. Heres a link for more detailed answer.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: I specifically told element should not be focusable, and tabindex attribute makes them focusable.